# 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteScript' and no extension method 'ExecuteScript'

Tags: c#, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afTTv.jpg)Getting error in (ExecuteScript) while running the code, please solve it

```
for (int second = 0; ; second++)
{
     if (second >= 60)
     {
        break;
     }
     river.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,150)", "");
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: What type is `river`?

Comment: @ChrisF river is the object of IWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to perform a Javascript execution and your "river" type is WebDriver

use this code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)river;

                for (int second = 0; ; second++)
                {
                     if (second >= 60)
                     {
                        break;
                     }
                    jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,150)", new object[] { element });

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
```

here element--> IwebElement

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem m facing is image is not capturing in proper format as i want, the screen capture code i m written thr is working and n images got captured from top to bottom... but one issue is thr at the bottom/center of the captured image ''menu bar/search bar'' is appearing which makes the image partitioned at centered/bottom.. (ref: Screenshot Attached  from description )

Comment: Never came across such long screenshots :D ..Need information on Device taken and config @s-shaikh